# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__ in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to set player speed, but i get this error `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__`. How can I work with that speed in other class. I have no idea, why is there this error, because I found `self.ids` on internet. Those people didn't have that error, but I have,why? How to solve it? Thanks

> **My python:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.graphics import RoundedRectangle, Color
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'maximized')
Builder.load_file("game.kv")
class Menu(Screen):
    pass
class LevelSelection(Screen):
    pass
class Level1(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/30)
    def update(self, *args):
        self.ids.player.speed += 500* 1/30
        self.ids.Player.y += self.ids.player.speed * 1 /30
class Game(Screen):
    pass
class Player(Image):
    speed = NumericProperty(0)
class Full(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Menu(name="menu"))
        sm.add_widget(LevelSelection(name="levels"))
        sm.add_widget(Game(name="game"))
        sm.add_widget(Level1(name="level1"))
        return sm
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Full().run()
```

> **My .kv:**

```
<MenuButton@Button>:
    font_size :"50sp"
    background_normal : "bt1_normal.png"
    background_down : "bt1_down.png"
    border:90,90,90,90
<Level@Button>:
    font_size :"50sp"
    background_normal : "bt2_normal.png"
    background_down : "bt2_down.png"
<LevelSelection>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color: 
                rgba:1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
                source:"backgrounf.png"
        orientation:"vertical"
        padding:"100dp", "10dp"
        spacing:"150dp"
        Widget:
        BoxLayout:
            padding:"100dp"
            spacing:"100dp"
            Level:
                text:"1"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "level1"
                
<Menu>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color: 
                rgba:1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
                source:"backgrounf.png"
        orientation:"vertical"
        padding:"200dp", "50dp"
        spacing:"150dp"
        Widget:
        BoxLayout:
            padding:"100dp"
            spacing:"150dp"
            MenuButton:
                text:"start"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "levels"
            MenuButton:
                text:"exit"
                on_release:
                    app.stop()
<Player>:
    source:"player.png"
<Level1>:
    FloatLayout
        Player:
            id:player
            allow_stretch:True
            size_hint:None,None
            size:root.height/15,root.height/15
            x:root.width/20
            y:root.height/2
```

Comment: Perhaps `self.ids.Player.y ` should be `self.ids.player.y ` (capitalization).

Comment: No I try both, didn't work

Comment: The symbol you use after `ids` must exactly match whatever you set as an `id` in your `kv`.